# Hibernate persistance.xml : Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

My `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.ibm.apiscanner.DTO.BaselineDTO</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url"    value="jdbc:db2://localhost:{PORT}/{DB}" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="{user}" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="{password}" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect"/>
      <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm presented with the following:

```
Jan 22, 2015 9:16:48 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
Jan 22, 2015 9:16:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
```

The same url,user and password combination works when connecting via basic JDBC.

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: "For me the reason was obvious: connection was null because the database was not responding." I added that as answer, but it was not suitable for someone, thus got downvoted. I leave the information here for completeness, if someone like me stumples to this question with same etimology of symthoms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an INFO message (nothing to worry about) because you set:

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
```

By default, if you don't specify this property, it will then be set to true, and a JDBC connection will be used to inspect the database metadata.

So you have two options:

1. You remove that property
2. You keep it, but you add this property as well:

   ```
   hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
   ```

   but then you will get some other INFO message, telling that:

   ```
   HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
   ```

Comment: I deleted the property, nothing changed. How do I check if the connection is good?  `.persist()` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Maybe the connection is not working. Just use your DB client and try connecting to the same URL/user/password.

Comment: The same url,user and password combination works when connecting via basic JDBC

Comment: Strange. That's how it should behave with Hibernate 4.3.7. I have no other clue. You need to add debugging in this case.

Comment: 4.3.7? My jar is version 4.3.5, would that make a difference?

Comment: Probably not. If you say the connection is not working, then that's a bigger problem than the INFO message.

Comment: Okay, not sure how to resolve this but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It was a driver version problem for me,

-Make you have  db2jcc4.jar and it is not conflicting with earlier version .

-Make sure you have specified currentschema